# Halide Func Constructor

Tags: c++, halide

I am reading source code of Halide, and the constructor of Func looks wierd, anyone knows what does these underlines mean? Thanks.

```
template<typename T>                                                        
HALIDE_NO_USER_CODE_INLINE explicit Func(Buffer<T> &im) : Func() {          
    (*this)(_) = im(_);                                                     
}
```

Comment: They are names of a variable.

Comment: @Fureeish I finally realize _ is a valid variable name, thanks a lot!